# Why do some users ask duplicates of their own questions?

Tags: discussion, questions, duplicate-questions, closed-questions

[This question was closed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3947346/how-to-count-model-of-car-closed) as a duplicate to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3942695/how-to-count-of-model-of-car).

I was one of the people who voted to close it as a duplicate, but I can't figure out for the life of me why some users would ask the *exact* same question twice, within a few hours of each other? (Now, this isn't the first time I came across something like this on Stack Overflow.) It's almost as though all they did was copy-and-paste the contents of their first question into the second question!

Comment: Isn't it obvious that he does not know how to use the SO interface? He added a supplement to his question as answer. Some people are not used to the edit functionality (or maybe they do not find the link; we had some questions about that on Meta). Or as Kop stated: they can't find it anymore.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Because their first question did not get enough attention and they wanted to see if the second one gets better luck!

Maybe they wanted to see if they could get some points with it.

But with all due respect for people who do this:

Sometimes the answer may be simple: THEY ARE IDIOTS.

Comment: Normally I would agree, but the question I linked it has plenty of attention, with people commenting for further clarification!

Comment: Don't forget, they sometimes do this if their previous question is closed. Or because they don't know how to edit their question. (O wait this is caught by the last reason).

Comment: You're a tool Andrew, I have asked the same question a number of time because IDIOTS jump in and the question seems to slip away due to all the people trying to score points with no answer!

Answer (score 10):

I think the most logical explanation is that they couldn't find it anymore; SO doesn't make it *super obvious* to find your own questions, add to that the fact that the user doesn't seem very smart and..

Comment: If they're a registered user a link to the question will be sitting on their profile page.

Comment: @ChrisF, that supposes that they've noticed that they HAVE a profile page :)

Comment: @Benjol - now that's one possibility I hadn't considered!

Comment: @ChrisF, I wouldn't have suggested it except that I'm pretty sure that I chanced on someone in a chat last week who didn't know, obviously I can't find the link now.

Comment: @Benjol: We had one such user [on our SE meta](http://meta.cooking.stackexchange.com/q/657/41).  Surprised me too, but it does happen.  I guess, when you're used to stuff like phpBB, you tend to think of a "profile" page as not containing anything particularly important.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes asking the same basic quesion in a different way can lead to more/better answers.

Comment: True, but in this case the OP asked the same question twice in the exact same way.